# AppEngine: Reading values/settings from app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

Is it possible to read settings in Python from my app.yaml configuration file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; app.yaml isn't uploaded to your application directory by default.  You could symlink to it with a different filename in the project directory and then read from there if it's really necessary.  What settings are you trying to access?

Comment: The appid is available in os.environ['APPLICATION_ID'].  The version is, I believe, os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'], although this appears to be the minor version.

Comment: os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID'] is of the form major.minor.